# create multiple tag docker image

Tags: docker, tags

How can several tags be attached to one Docker image? Is it possible to create multiple tags using **one Dockerfile**?

It is possible, *somehow*; for example `docker pull ubuntu` will get several images, some of which have multiple tags:

```
ubuntu                  13.10               9f676bd305a4        2 weeks ago         182.1 MB
ubuntu                  saucy               9f676bd305a4        2 weeks ago         182.1 MB
ubuntu                  raring              eb601b8965b8        2 weeks ago         170.2 MB
ubuntu                  13.04               eb601b8965b8        2 weeks ago         170.2 MB
ubuntu                  12.10               5ac751e8d623        2 weeks ago         161.4 MB
ubuntu                  quantal             5ac751e8d623        2 weeks ago         161.4 MB
ubuntu                  10.04               9cc9ea5ea540        2 weeks ago         183 MB
ubuntu                  lucid               9cc9ea5ea540        2 weeks ago         183 MB
ubuntu                  12.04               9cd978db300e        2 weeks ago         204.7 MB
ubuntu                  latest              9cd978db300e        2 weeks ago         204.7 MB
ubuntu                  precise             9cd978db300e        2 weeks ago         204.7 MB
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080706/how-to-create-named-and-latest-tag-in-docker

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can't create tags with Dockerfiles but you can create multiple tags on your images via the command line.

Use this to list your image ids:

```
$ docker images
```

Then tag away:

```
$ docker tag 9f676bd305a4 ubuntu:13.10
$ docker tag 9f676bd305a4 ubuntu:saucy
$ docker tag eb601b8965b8 ubuntu:raring
...
```

Comment: The major point is in Dockerfile, these commands could not be written into Dockerfile.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081272/119527) for a way that avoids having to manually figure out the ID.

Answer (score 776):

**Since 1.10 release**, you can now add multiple tags at once on build:

```
docker build -t name1:tag1 -t name1:tag2 -t name2 .
```

Source: [Add ability to add multiple tags with docker build](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15780)

Official Docker doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-an-image--t

Comment: I think this is the more correct answer for ease of use in a build process

Comment: This is not proper, because the ubuntu's tag for different version, the content is diffident.

Comment: How do I get these tags to appear in the repository after a push though? Unfortunately, only the one I use in the push command appears in the repo.

Comment: Even at the end of 2018 Docker is still incredibly immature in this respect, each 'tag' must *still* be pushed separately despite being attached to the same image.  What is required here is some capability similar to Git tags.

Comment: @EdRandall it doesn't matter because if the image already exist in your repo then docker just adds the tag to the image instead of pushing the entire image again.

Comment: almost didn't upvote because I'd nudge it to 667 

Comment: You can now push with an --all-tags flag to push all tags at once.

Comment: @giterdone it seems like `--all-tags` is going to push every single tag associated with an image, which may not actually be what somebody wanted to do after building with, say, 2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

### Tags must be scoped for repo:

I tried the accepted answer but my tags were ignored and just "latest" tag produced.

Reviewing the logs I saw an error was puked at the very end about lacking a scope, so realized that I needed to prepend my username before the name:tag:

The form should be:

```
-t <dockerhub uname>/name1:tag1 -t <dockerhub uname>/name1:tag2 etc...
```

ie: From the `buildx` command pushing to Docker Hub we'd tag as below:

```
docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/arm64 --push -t f1linux/postfix:3.7.2-r0 . -t f1linux/postfix:aarch64 -t f1linux/postfix:arm64
```

Answer (score -15):

**HOW NOT TO DO IT!:**

When building an image, you could also tag it this way.

```
docker build -t ubuntu:14.04 .
```

Then you build it again with another tag:

```
docker build -t ubuntu:latest .
```

*If* your Dockerfile makes good use of the cache, the same image should come out, and it effectively does the same as retagging the same image. If you do `docker images` then you will see that they have the same ID.

There's probably a case where this goes wrong though...
But like @david-braun said, you can't create tags with Dockerfiles themselves, just with the docker command.

Comment: I might add that doing it like @david-braun is cleaner.

Comment: Don't build twice. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081272/119527).

Comment: build twice defeats the notion of CI/CD... the second compile could be difference depending on dependencies... it's all in the timing.

Comment: With the clear 'How not to do it' heading this answer does now add something to the understanding of how it works.