# How to create named and latest tag in Docker?

Tags: docker, tags

Supposed I have an image that I want to tag as `0.10.24` (in my case it's an image containing Node.js 0.10.24). I built that image using a Dockerfile and executing `docker build` and by providing a tag using the `-t` parameter.

I expect that one day I will have additional versions of that image, so I will rerun the process, just with another tag name.

So far, so good. This works great and fine and all is well.

But, and this is where problems start, I also want to always have the newest image tagged ad `latest` additionally. So I guess I need to give two names to the very same image.

How do I do this? Do I really need to re-run `docker build` on the exact same version again, but this time use another tag, is is there a better option?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928780/create-multiple-tag-docker-image

Answer (score 466, accepted):

You can have multiple tags when building the image:

```
$ docker build -t whenry/fedora-jboss:latest -t whenry/fedora-jboss:v2.1 .
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-image-t

Comment: you can also leave off the `:latest` portion, as that is the default: `docker build -t whenry/fedora-jboss -t whenry/fedora-jboss:v2.1 .`

Comment: @TemporalWolf is using :latest a bad practice? I know what (bad things) can happen when you :latest tag. But no where could I find that it says it's a bad practice. Do you have any references? 
I am not using :latest in prod but just in CICD as we don't use skaffold or anything, one will have to change the tag in cicd file every time there's a change in the dockerfile.

Comment: @Raaka One could argue explicit is better than implicit, but it's the default: whether you use it or not has no bearing on the outcome. Personally, I'm of the opinion either way works. Just pick one way and consistently do it that way.

Answer (score 221):

Once you have your image, you can use

```
$ docker tag <image> <newName>/<repoName>:<tagName>
```

1. Build and tag the image with creack/node:latest

   ```
   $ ID=$(docker build -q -t creack/node .)
   ```
2. Add a new tag

   ```
   $ docker tag $ID creack/node:0.10.24
   ```
3. You can use this and skip the -t part from build

   ```
   $ docker tag $ID creack/node:latest
   ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore? The build command doesn't return the image id, ID contains the entire build log

Comment: The build logs are supposed to be on stderr, you can open a bugreport on github. Otherwise, when you build with -t, you can use directly the given tag and discard altogether the image id. In my example, the first line produce an image `creack/node:latest`, you can then tag it with `docker tag creack/node:latest creack/node:0.10.24`

Comment: This works well with something like ```REV=$(hg identify --num)```

Comment: To make the latest tag work properly, you will probably want to do
`docker tag -f $ID creack/node:latest` in order to force the tagging with latest (in case a previous image was already latest)

Comment: The part with "You can use this and skip the -t part from build" does not apply for docker 1.6.2. If you leave out the `-t creack/node`, you image will not have a name (it will appear as <none>) so you will not be able to tag it with the following commands.

Comment: @treaz But the point is, `docker build` always outputs the image ID when it's finished. So it doesn't need a name (because you're about to "name" (tag) it).

Comment: I noticed, that `docker build -t registry-ip:port/repository/name` tags image as `:latest` automatically.

Then, I tag it with particular version.
`docker tag 'registry-ip:port/repository/name' 'registry-ip:port/repository/name:v1.0'`

But, what if need to push them both to repository:
I ran `docker push registry-ip:port/repository/name` without specifying tags and it pushes 2 images.

Comment: Use:  ID=$(docker build -q -t myrepo/myname:mytag . ) .  The "-q" means only the ID is written to stdout.  You should always specify a tag, as if you don't the tag 'latest' will be used, even if you are building of an old branch.

Answer (score 70):

Here is my bash script

```
docker build -t ${IMAGE}:${VERSION} .
docker tag ${IMAGE}:${VERSION} ${IMAGE}:latest
```

You can then remove untagged images if you rebuilt the same version with

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk "{print $3}")
```

[link](http://jimhoskins.com/2013/07/27/remove-untagged-docker-images.html)

or

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f3 | tr '\n' ' ')
```

or

**Clean up commands**:

Docker 1.13 introduces clean-up commands. To remove all unused containers, images, networks and volumes:

```
docker system prune
```

or individually:

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
docker volume prune
```

Comment: On my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) `awk '{print $3}'` works but not `awk "{print $3}"` so the command I use is `docker rmi $(docker images -a | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $3}')`

Comment: the `-f` option no longer exists in `docker tag`. Usage is just `docker tag IMAGE[:TAG] IMAGE[:TAG]`

Comment: @2Fast2BCn: Assuming you also need to `docker push` after `docker build & docker run`, do you push with `:latest` or `${VERSION}`?

Comment: You can push both I guess. It will store it only once anyway.

Answer (score 22):

`ID=$(docker build -t creack/node .)` doesn't work for me since `ID` will contain the output from the build.

SO I'm using this small BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail

IMAGE=...your image name...
VERSION=...the version...

docker build -t ${IMAGE}:${VERSION} . | tee build.log || exit 1
ID=$(tail -1 build.log | awk '{print $3;}')
docker tag $ID ${IMAGE}:latest

docker images | grep ${IMAGE}

docker run --rm ${IMAGE}:latest /opt/java7/bin/java -version
```

Comment: Or you can just pass `-q` / `--quiet` to `build` as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081272/884640)

Answer (score 9):

Just **grep the ID** from `docker images`:

```
docker build -t creack/node:latest .
ID="$(docker images | grep 'creak/node' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')"
docker tag "$ID" creack/node:0.10.24
docker tag "$ID" creack/node:latest
```

Needs *no temporary file* and gives **full build output**. You still can redirect it to `/dev/null` or a log file.

Answer (score 9):

To give tag to a docker file during build command:

```
docker build -t image_name:tag_name .
```

otherwise it will give `latest` tag to your docker image automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Variation of Aaron's answer.
Using sed without temporary files

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=1.0.0
IMAGE=company/image
ID=$(docker build  -t ${IMAGE}  .  | tail -1 | sed 's/.*Successfully built \(.*\)$/\1/')

docker tag ${ID} ${IMAGE}:${VERSION}
docker tag -f ${ID} ${IMAGE}:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Hye it's very easy you just need to follow the below steps -

So, to create and tagging an image in Docker we can use the following commands

First take out your **Docker id** by running the below command

```
docker ps
```

**Copy** -> Names

```
docker build -t dockerId/Name of your image you want:latest .
```

> For me I use
> `docker build -t condescending_greider/newdoc:latest .`

Thanks for your time