# How to delete images from a private docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I run a private docker registry, and I want to delete all images but the `latest` from a repository. I don't want to delete the entire repository, just some of the images inside it. The [API docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) don't mention a way to do this, but surely it's possible?

Comment: @MichaelZelensky i tried a 'tag' for <reference> but that didn't work for me. which <reference> should i use/how to obtain it? (using this registry:  https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/  from October 2020 )

Comment: @Melardev
_api.md#delete-manifest_
`Note that a manifest can only be deleted by digest`
_api.md#digest-parameter_
`sha256:6c3c624b58dbbcd3c0dd82b4c53f04194d1247c6eebdaab7c610cf7d66709b3b`
and env required for deletion in registry:
`REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=TRUE`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Currently you cannot use the Registry API for that task. It only allows you to delete a repository or a specific tag.

In general, deleting a repository means, that all the tags associated to this repo are deleted.

Deleting a tag means, that the association between an image and a tag is deleted.

None of the above will delete a single image. They are left on your disk.

---

## Workaround

**For this workaround you need to have your docker images stored locally.**

A workaround for your solution would be to delete all but the latest tags and thereby potentially removing the reference to the associated images. Then you can run **[this script](https://gist.github.com/kwk/c5443f2a1abcf0eb1eaa)** to remove all images, that are not referenced by any tag or the ancestry of any used image.

### Terminology (images and tags)

Consider an image graph like this where the capital letters (`A`, `B`, ...) represent short image IDs and `<-` means that an image is based on another image:

```
 A <- B <- C <- D
```

Now we add tags to the picture:

```
 A <- B <- C <- D
           |    |
           |    <version2>
           <version1>
```

Here, the tag `<version1>` references the image `C` and the tag `<version2>` references the image `D`.

### Refining your question

In your question you said that you wanted to remove

> all images but the `latest`

. Now, this terminology is not quite correct. You've mixed images and tags. Looking at the graph I think you would agree that the tag `<version2>` represents the latest version. In fact, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080706/how-to-create-named-and-latest-tag-in-docker) you can have a tag that represents the latest version:

```
 A <- B <- C <- D
           |    |
           |    <version2>
           |    <latest>
           <version1>
```

Since the `<latest>` tag references image `D` I ask you: do you really want to delete all but image `D`? Probably not!

### What happens if you delete a tag?

If you delete the tag `<version1>` using the Docker REST API you will get this:

```
 A <- B <- C <- D
                |
                <version2>
                <latest>
```

**Remember:** Docker will never delete an image! Even if it did, in this case it cannot delete an image, since the image `C` is part of the ancestry for the image `D` which is tagged.

Even if you use **[this script](https://gist.github.com/kwk/c5443f2a1abcf0eb1eaa)**, no image will be deleted.

### When an image can be deleted

Under the condition that you can control when somebody can pull or push to your registry (e.g. by disabling the REST interface). You can delete an image from an image graph if no other image is based on it and no tag refers to it.

Notice that in the following graph, the image `D` is **not** based on `C` but on `B`. Therefore, `D` doesn't depend on `C`. If you delete tag `<version1>` in this graph, the image `C` will not be used by any image and **[this script](https://gist.github.com/kwk/c5443f2a1abcf0eb1eaa)** can remove it.

```
 A <- B <--------- D
      \            |
       \           <version2>
        \          <latest>
         \ <- C
              |
              <version1>
```

After the cleanup your image graph looks like this:

```
 A <- B <- D
           |
           <version2>
           <latest>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: You're right--deleting the tags didn't actually delete the associated images. Is there any way to delete the images given ssh access to the box, then?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a workaround that does the job for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly it--I understand that images are built incrementally, but I need a way to prune those dead branches. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradKleine how do you make the images graph out of the list of images you get from the registry?

Comment: @RafaelBarros The image "graph" is nothing more than a simple list of image IDs. Take a look at this script https://gist.github.com/kwk/c5443f2a1abcf0eb1eaa . It operates not on the Registry API but on the file system. It's just a matter of collecting all image IDs we have in a list and removing those from the list that are part of another image's ancestry. The remainder are those images that can be deleted. (I quite often use the term image and layer interchangeably.)

Comment: Garbage collecting has finally arrived to the Registry v2.4.0 https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/

Comment: I check your script ... why go all through these hassle? I know the uuid value of the tag, and I know the repo name. I also know, that my image has no ancestry, (except the base ubuntu). So I can just login and 'rm -rf' the corresponding folders. And by the way, /var/lib/* is not always the location, so the script felt risky.

Comment: @daixtr I know that the script isn't perfect but it it gives a start. If you have the knowledge that you have regarding ancestry of your image you can go in an delete whatever you like but for a more systematic approach you need to go through all the hassle or upgrade to registry 2.4.0 at least as markus-lindberg pointed out.

Comment: one doubt, even if I am restarting the raspi where registry server is setup with some images in the private repo, all the images are lost.

I tried passing restart = always.

Comment: There's no `registry` in my `/var/lib/docker/` dir.

Answer (score 142):

I've faced the same problem with my registry, then I tried the solution listed below from a blog page. It works.

Do note, the deletion must be enabled for it to work. You can do it by providing a custom config, or by setting `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`.

### Step 1: [List the repositories](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/api/#listing-repositories)

```
$ curl -sS <domain-on-ip>:5000/v2/_catalog
```

The response will be in the following format:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    <repo>,
    ...
  ]
}
```

### Step 2: [List the repository tags](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/api/#listing-image-tags)

```
$ curl -sS <domain-on-ip>:5000/v2/<repo>/tags/list
```

The response will be in the following format:

```
{
    "name": <repo>,
    "tags": [
        <tag>,
        ...
    ]
}
```

### Step 3: [Determine the digest of the target tag](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/api/#pulling-an-image-manifest)

```
$ curl -sS -H 'Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' \
-o /dev/null \
-w '%header{Docker-Content-Digest}' \
<domain-or-ip>:5000/v2/<repo>/manifests/<tag>
```

Do note, the `Accept` header is needed here. Without it you'll get a different value and the deletion will fail.

Note the `-w` option is only supported in CURL v7.83.0 and above. In older versions of CURL you will need to use another tool such as sed, grep or awk to extract the header content from the output.

The response will be in the following format:

```
sha256:6de813fb93debd551ea6781e90b02f1f93efab9d882a6cd06bbd96a07188b073
```

### Step 4: [Delete the manifest](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/api/#deleting-an-image)

```
$ curl -sS -X DELETE <domain-or-ip>:5000/v2/<repo>/manifests/<digest>
```

Note that you need to include the

### Step 5: [Garbage collect the image](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/about/garbage-collection/#run-garbage-collection)

Run this command in your docker registry container:

```
$ registry garbage-collect -m /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

Here is my config.yml:

```yaml
version: 0.1
log:
    fields:
    service: registry
storage:
    cache:
        blobdescriptor: inmemory
    filesystem:
        rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
    delete:
        enabled: true
http:
    addr: :5000
    headers:
        X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
    storagedriver:
        enabled: true
        interval: 10s
        threshold: 3
```

Comment: The commands succeeded, including messages about "`Deleteing blob: /docker/...`" but it didn't change the disk space used.  Using _bin/registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.4.1_.

Comment: to delete an image, you should run the registry container with REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true parameter.

Comment: I set "delete: enabled" value to true in /etc/docker/registry/config.yml file. For this configuration no need to set REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED variable @AdilIlhan

Comment: re: step 3, the "Docker-Content-Digest" must be in the header? (not seeing it in the curl output).  Should I be able to see the results of marking a manifest before deleting the marked manifest(s) to know I successfully marked it?  It seems to give me a 202 response no matter what I send it.

Comment: the `Docker-Content-Digest` part should be in lowercase (tested on docker engine v18.09.2)

i.e. `curl -v --silent -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/<name>/manifests/<tag> 2>&1 | grep docker-content-digest | awk '{print ($3)}'`

Comment: In the step 3 the part with `awk` must be in that way `awk '{print $2}'` and add the option `-I` to the `curl` command !!

Comment: Thank you, this is the first answer that worked for me. I was missing `Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` header and kept on getting `MANIFEST_UNKNOWN` error. Even though it's somewhere in their documentation(https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) it's very confusing.

Comment: Steps 3 doesn't return any output (not even an errors !!), any suggestions !

Comment: @TomaszW Good you thing you pointed out the header. Somehow I overlooked this every time I was reading around. Saved me.

Comment: Note that also for the delete the header has to be set. See https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/api/#deleting-an-image

Comment: you should add one more step

Step6:
rm -r /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/<name>/<tag>

Answer (score 92):

The current `v2` registry now supports deleting via `DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>`.

See: https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#deleting-an-image

The `<reference>` can be taken from the `Docker-Content-Digest` header of a `GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<tag>` request (do note that the `Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` header is needed for this request).

A script that makes use of it: https://github.com/byrnedo/docker-reg-tool

For it to work deletion must be enabled (`REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`).

And to really free the disk space you need to run [garbage collection](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/).

Comment: Some other answers here show how to extract manifest reference hash.  This is necessary to translate a tag into something to pass to `DELETE`.

Comment: Getting unsupported error. I have given proper digest value as the reference.

Comment: @Winster: what version of registry are you connecting to?

Comment: v2. My disk image size has grown to 65GB mostly contributed by deleted registry containers and finally I had to reset to factory.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 updated with instructions about getting the reference hash.

Comment: on V2 too and getting error `{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}`

Comment: ```{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}``` any suggestion ?

Comment: To fix the `UNSUPPORTED` issue, env var needs to be set `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`.

Answer (score 23):

This is really ugly but it works, text is tested on registry:2.5.1.
I did not manage to get delete working smoothly even after updating configuration to enable delete. The ID was really difficult to retrieve, had to login to get it, maybe some misunderstanding. Anyway, the following works:

1. Enter the container

   ```
    docker exec -it registry sh
   ```
2. Define variables matching your container and container version:

   ```
    export NAME="google/cadvisor"
    export VERSION="v0.24.1"
   ```
3. Move to the the registry directory:

   ```
    cd /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2
   ```
4. Delete files related to your hash:

   ```
    find . | grep `ls ./repositories/$NAME/_manifests/tags/$VERSION/index/sha256`| xargs rm -rf $1
   ```
5. Delete manifests:

   ```
    rm -rf ./repositories/$NAME/_manifests/tags/$VERSION
   ```
6. Logout

   ```
    exit
   ```
7. Run the GC:

   ```
    docker exec -it registry  bin/registry garbage-collect  /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
   ```
8. If all was done properly some information about deleted blobs is shown.

Comment: i followed the same steps mentioned above, but when i checked the docker registry {container} disk usage it was showing same as before doing the steps... any idea why?

Comment: doesn't work. Easy to check. When you do the following steps and push the repo again it says "064794e955a6: Layer already exists "

Comment: This is indeed ugly. And there are better ways these days.

Answer (score 20):

**Problem 1**

You mentioned it was your private docker registry, so you probably need to check [Registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) instead of [Hub registry API doc](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/hub_registry_spec/#the-api), which is the link you provided.

**Problem 2**

docker registry API is a client/server protocol, it is up to the server's implementation on whether to remove the images in the back-end. (I guess)

```
DELETE /v1/repositories/(namespace)/(repository)/tags/(tag*)
```

**Detailed explanation**

Below I demo how it works now from your description as my understanding for your questions.

I run a private docker registry.
I use the default one, and listen on port `5000`.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry
```

Then I tag the local image and push into it.

```
$ docker tag ubuntu localhost:5000/ubuntu
$ docker push localhost:5000/ubuntu
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/ubuntu] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository localhost:5000/ubuntu (1 tags)
511136ea3c5a: Image successfully pushed
d7ac5e4f1812: Image successfully pushed
2f4b4d6a4a06: Image successfully pushed
83ff768040a0: Image successfully pushed
6c37f792ddac: Image successfully pushed
e54ca5efa2e9: Image successfully pushed
Pushing tag for rev [e54ca5efa2e9] on {http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags/latest}
```

After that I can use **Registry API** to check it exists in your private docker registry

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:5000/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags
{"latest": "e54ca5efa2e962582a223ca9810f7f1b62ea9b5c3975d14a5da79d3bf6020f37"}
```

Now I can delete the tag using that API !!

```
$ curl -X DELETE localhost:5000/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags/latest
true
```

Check again, the tag doesn't exist in my private registry server

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:5000/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags/latest
{"error": "Tag not found"}
```

Comment: Please, see my answer below for an explanation why this command doesn't help.

Comment: You delete tags but not the image data. The latter is done by the script I reference after you have deleted a tag. I also use the registry API to delete a tag.

Comment: it is upto each registry API server's implementation, from protocol's point of view, it doesn't exist.

Comment: You're right that it's up to the implementation--but I was/am looking for a way to delete image data from the canonical `registry` image. SSHing in and running a script works, even if it's not ideal.

As a side note I still think it's an incomplete API--you can delete tags, but if you GET `/images` you still see all the leftover image data.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Registry API, was looking for a way to DELETE an image in private registry. This method is good enough for me even if it's just 'untagging' without actually free up disk space.

Comment: How to delete the image from Registry 2.0?

Comment: This 'curl' method to delete tags is very helpful. Thank you good sir.

Comment: @KonradKleine you focus so much about the tag<->image difference in your answer that you actually forgot to answer what was asked. This is what LarryCai did better

Comment: I think this is the only technically correct answer in this thread.

Comment: Note, that this is the solution for `v1`. But I have `v2`:(

Answer (score 16):

There are some clients (in Python, Ruby, etc) which do exactly that. For my taste, it isn't sustainable to install a runtime (e.g. Python) on my registry server, just to housekeep my registry!

---

So [`deckschrubber`](https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/deckschrubber) is my solution:

```
go install github.com/fraunhoferfokus/deckschrubber@latest
$GOPATH/bin/deckschrubber
```

images older than a given age are automatically deleted. Age can be specified using `-year`, `-month`, `-day`, or a combination of them:

```
$GOPATH/bin/deckschrubber -month 2 -day 13 -registry http://registry:5000
```

---

**UPDATE**: [here's a short introduction](https://blog.quaintous.com/2017/05/19/docker-registry-housekeeping/) on deckschrubber.

Comment: `deckschrubber` is pretty good - very easy to install (single binary), and lets you delete images by name (with regex match) as well as age.

Comment: `ERRO[0000] Could not delete image!                       repo=.... tag=latest` :/

Comment: @scythargon impossible to say wether your specification is correct.

Comment: Warning: did literally nothing on my repository.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not remove images which don't have tags. So if you keep pushing images on a single tag, it will only check the one which is tagged, not the other ones.

Comment: @Krystian please file an issue on GitHub if you don't mind. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The requirement to delete all tags except `latest` gets complicated because the same image manifest can be pointed to by multiple tags, so when you delete a manifest for one tag, you may effectively delete multiple tags.

There are a few options to make that workable. One is to track the digest for the latest tag and only delete manifests for other digests, or you can use some different API calls to delete the tags themselves.

---

Regardless of how you implement this, first your registry needs to be configured to allow the delete API's. With the minimal `registry:2` image, that involves starting it with an environment variable `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true` (or the equivalent yaml config).

Then for a simple script to loop through the tags and delete, there's:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
repo="localhost:5000/repo/to/prune"
for tag in $(regctl tag ls $repo); do
  if [ "$tag" != "latest" ]; then
    echo "Deleting: $(regctl image digest --list "${repo}:${tag}") [$tag]"
    regctl tag rm "${repo}:${tag}"
  fi
done
```

The `regctl` command used here comes from [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) and the `regctl tag rm` logic first attempts to perform the tag delete API added recently to the [distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#content-management). Since most registries haven't implemented that spec, it falls back to the manifest delete API, but it first creates a dummy manifest to overwrite the tag, and then deletes that new digest. In doing so, if the old manifest was in use by other tags, it doesn't delete those other tags.

An alternative version of the script that deletes manifests except those pointing to the `latest` digest looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
repo="localhost:5000/repo/to/prune"
save="$(regctl image digest --list "${repo}:latest")"
for tag in $(regctl tag ls $repo); do
  digest="$(regctl image digest --list "${repo}:${tag}")"
  if [ "$digest" != "$save" ]; then
    echo "Deleting: $digest [$tag]"
    regctl manifest rm "${repo}@${digest}"
  fi
done
```

If you find yourself needing to create a deletion policy to automate the deleting of lots of images, I'd recommend looking at `regclient/regbot` from the same repo which allows you to define that policy and leave it running to continuously prune your registry.

---

Once the images have been deleted, you'll need to [garbage collect](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/) your registry in most use cases. For example with the `registry:2` image that looks like:

```bash
docker exec registry /bin/registry garbage-collect \
  /etc/docker/registry/config.yml --delete-untagged
```

**Caution:** there is an [open issue](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3178) with the garbage-collect utility that will delete untagged child manifests of a multi-platform image. If you are using multi-platform images, you'll need to ensure every platform specific image is tagged or avoid using the above GC command until the issue has been resolved in your deployed version.

Answer (score 3):

Another tool you can use is [registry-cli](https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli). For example, this command:

```
registry.py -l "login:password" -r https://your-registry.example.com --delete
```

will delete all but the last 10 images.

Answer (score 3):

I am usually all for doing things with scripts, but if you are already running
a registry UI container built from [Joxit/docker-registry-ui](https://github.com/Joxit/docker-registry-ui), I found it easier to just opt-click the delete button in the UI and delete a page of images at a time, then garbage collect after.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly;

1) You must typed following command for RepoDigests of a docker repo;

```
## docker inspect <registry-host>:<registry-port>/<image-name>:<tag>
> docker inspect 174.24.100.50:8448/example-image:latest


[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:16c5af74ed970b1671fe095e063e255e0160900a0e12e1f8a93d75afe2fb860c",
        "RepoTags": [
            "174.24.100.50:8448/example-image:latest",
            "example-image:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "174.24.100.50:8448/example-image@sha256:5580b2110c65a1f2567eeacae18a3aec0a31d88d2504aa257a2fecf4f47695e6"
        ],
...
...
```

> ${digest} =
>   sha256:5580b2110c65a1f2567eeacae18a3aec0a31d88d2504aa257a2fecf4f47695e6

2) Use registry REST API

```
  ##curl -u username:password -vk -X DELETE registry-host>:<registry-port>/v2/<image-name>/manifests/${digest}


  >curl -u example-user:example-password -vk -X DELETE http://174.24.100.50:8448/v2/example-image/manifests/sha256:5580b2110c65a1f2567eeacae18a3aec0a31d88d2504aa257a2fecf4f47695e6
```

You should get a 202 Accepted for a successful invocation.

3-) Run Garbage Collector

```
docker exec registry bin/registry garbage-collect --dry-run /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

**registry** — registry container name.

For more detail explanation [enter link description here](https://medium.com/better-programming/cleanup-your-docker-registry-ef0527673e3a)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a way you can remove some old images from repository just based on the date when it was created.

To do that enter your docker registry container and get the list of manifest's revisions for some specific repository:

```
ls -latr /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/YOUR_REPO/_manifests/revisions/sha256/
```

The output then may be used within the request (with sha256 prefix):

```
curl -v --silent -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X DELETE http://DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST:5000/v2/YOUR_REPO/manifests/sha256:OUTPUT_LINE
```

And of course do not forget to execute 'garbage-collect' command after that:

```
bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

This docker image includes a bash script that can be used to remove images from a remote v2 registry : 
https://hub.docker.com/r/vidarl/remove_image_from_registry/

Answer (score 1):

Below Bash Script Deletes all the tags located in registry except the latest.

```
for D in /registry-data/docker/registry/v2/repositories/*; do
if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
    if [ -z "$(ls -A ${D}/_manifests/tags/)" ]; then
        echo ''
    else
        for R in $(ls -t ${D}/_manifests/tags/ | tail -n +2); do
            digest=$(curl -k -I -s -H -X GET http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/v2/$(basename  ${D})/manifests/${R} -H 'accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'  | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print $2}' )
            url="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/v2/$(basename  ${D})/manifests/$digest"
            url=${url%$'\r'}
            curl -X DELETE -k -I -s   $url -H 'accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' 
        done
    fi
fi
done
```

After this Run

```
docker exec $(docker ps | grep registry | awk '{print $1}') /bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how to use this fine script?

Answer (score 1):

Simple ruby script based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43786939/2417790) answer: [registry_cleaner](https://github.com/oniksfly/registry_cleaner).

You can run it on local machine:

`./registry_cleaner.rb --host=https://registry.exmpl.com --repository=name --tags_count=4`

And then on the registry machine remove blobs with `/bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script based on Yavuz Sert's answer.
It deletes all tags that are not the latest version, and their tag is greater than 950.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


CheckTag(){
    Name=$1
    Tag=$2

    Skip=0
    if [[ "${Tag}" == "latest" ]]; then
        Skip=1
    fi
    if [[ "${Tag}" -ge "950" ]]; then
        Skip=1
    fi
    if [[ "${Skip}" == "1" ]]; then
        echo "skip ${Name} ${Tag}"
    else
        echo "delete ${Name} ${Tag}"
        Sha=$(curl -v -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/${Name}/manifests/${Tag} 2>&1 | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}')
        Sha="${Sha/$'\r'/}"
        curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X DELETE "http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/${Name}/manifests/${Sha}"
    fi
}

ScanRepository(){
    Name=$1
    echo "Repository ${Name}"
    curl -s http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/${Name}/tags/list | jq '.tags[]' |
    while IFS=$"\n" read -r line; do
        line="${line%\"}"
        line="${line#\"}"
        CheckTag $Name $line
    done
}


JqPath=$(which jq)
if [[ "x${JqPath}" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "Couldn't find jq executable."
  exit 2
fi

curl -s http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/_catalog | jq '.repositories[]' |
while IFS=$"\n" read -r line; do
    line="${line%\"}"
    line="${line#\"}"
    ScanRepository $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A script to remove all but the `latest` tag from an insecure registry (private, no auth):

```bash
#!/bin/sh -eu
repo=$1
registry=${2-localhost:5000}

tags=`curl -sS "$registry/v2/$repo/tags/list" | jq -r .tags[]`
tag2digest() {
    local tag=$1
    curl -sS -H 'Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' \
        -o /dev/null \
        -w '%header{Docker-Content-Digest}' \
        "$registry/v2/$repo/manifests/$tag"
}
latest_digest=`tag2digest latest`
digests=`echo "$tags" \
    | while IFS= read -r tag; do
        tag2digest "$tag"
        echo
    done \
    | sort \
    | uniq`
digests=`echo "$digests" \
    | grep -Fvx "$latest_digest"`
echo "$digests" \
    | while IFS= read -r digest; do
        curl -sS -X DELETE "$registry/v2/$repo/manifests/$digest"
    done
```

Usage:

```
$ ./rm-tags.sh <image> [<registry>]
```

After removing tags (or manifests to be more precise) run [garbage collection](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/#run-garbage-collection):

```
$ registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

To support Docker Hub and/or auth see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982176/52499) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73994558/52499).

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest solution that worked for my setup, using a private registry in a swarm cluster

Experimenting with whatever filter you need

```bash
docker images | grep 'your_own_filter'
```

`tail -n +4`: keep the last 3 images that got built

`awk '{print $3}'`: will extract the 3rd column, which is the 'IMAGE ID'

**Example:**

```bash
docker rmi $(docker images | grep 'your_own_filter' | tail -n +4 | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: How does this delete the images from the docker registry? The `docker rmi` command only deletes images from your local docker engine.