# Docker local repository deletion does not free space

Tags: docker

I am facing a problem. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I have created a local docker repository (dev, file system) and tried to push some local images on to the same.

The local images were saved on the repository and the GET requests showed the JSON contents.

but then, I wanted to delete these images from the repository and for that I used the HTTP DELETE requests, deleting the "library" and the images from the repository.
The problem is that the space eaten up by the images that were pushed to the repo has not been freed up.

I have deleted the container running the repository and also the repository image itself, but the space is still not freed up.
Strange is that the same is not visible in any of the system directories even id I do a du -hs /* in /.

Contents of the repo query attached.

```
[{
"Args": [
    "-c",
    "exec docker-registry"
],
"Config": {
    "AttachStderr": true,
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "Cmd": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "exec docker-registry"
    ],
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "Cpuset": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "Env": [
        "HOME=/",
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_CONFIG=/docker-registry/config/config_sample.yml",
        "SETTINGS_FLAVOR=dev"
    ],
    "ExposedPorts": {
        "5000/tcp": {}
    },
    "Hostname": "db6454154305",
    "Image": "registry",
    "Memory": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "NetworkDisabled": false,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "PortSpecs": null,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "User": "",
    "Volumes": {
        "/docker/registry": {}
    },
    "WorkingDir": ""
},
"Created": "2014-08-25T14:12:03.711327013Z",
"Driver": "aufs",
"ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": null,
    "CapAdd": null,
    "CapDrop": null,
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "Devices": [],
    "Dns": null,
    "DnsSearch": null,
    "Links": null,
    "LxcConf": [],
    "NetworkMode": "bridge",
    "PortBindings": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "",
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Privileged": false,
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
    "RestartPolicy": {
        "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
        "Name": ""
    },
    "VolumesFrom": null
},
"HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/db6454154305015c410c068e4d641d535fab1434edf91238ebd4bd5933fd159b/hostname",
"HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/db6454154305015c410c068e4d641d535fab1434edf91238ebd4bd5933fd159b/hosts",
"Id": "db6454154305015c410c068e4d641d535fab1434edf91238ebd4bd5933fd159b",
"Image": "cd3581c06bdcb2cfd877f79102b8e48a90e7fd723b4b4c6ee34d1f1dd6f64303",
"MountLabel": "",
"Name": "/dreamy_pike",
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"Path": "/bin/sh",
"ProcessLabel": "",
"ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/db6454154305015c410c068e4d641d535fab1434edf91238ebd4bd5933fd159b/resolv.conf",
"State": {
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "FinishedAt": "2014-08-26T06:21:16.792306236Z",
    "Paused": false,
    "Pid": 5645,
    "Restarting": false,
    "Running": true,
    "StartedAt": "2014-08-26T08:38:57.051361284Z"
},
"Volumes": {
    "/docker/registry": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/ae9ac9a2649acce729fde429586a7d1b4b7fe7ec834c12bea4b8b5519e2740a8"
},
"VolumesRW": {
    "/docker/registry": true
}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Posible answer:
[Deleting images from a private docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436742/deleting-images-from-a-private-docker-registry/25551160#25551160)

Cannot try if this works as I deleted my virtual machine.

But thanks anyway for the help Konrad Kleine
https://stackoverflow.com/users/835098/konrad-kleine