# How do I delete a docker image from docker hub via command line?

Tags: docker

I create docker image for testing in my Jenkins pipeline, uploading this to Docker hub and deploy those to Kubernetes. At the end of the testing process, I want to delete the test image from Docker hub (not from test machine). How do I delete docker hub image from command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete Docker's images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398087/how-can-i-delete-dockers-images)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I want to delete image from Docker hub using command line.

Comment: The original version didn't state that.

Comment: I have figured out how to do that . This is the final python script I came up with: https://github.com/appscode/libbuild/blob/master/docker.py#L31

Comment: Wow, I can't believe there's no docker command line to delete an image from a registry.

Comment: The question refers to Docker *Hub* and its `hub.docker.io` API does allow for deleting tags, like [my answer here shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209644/how-do-i-delete-a-docker-image-from-docker-hub-via-command-line/59334315#59334315)

Answer (score 13):

Use the Docker Hub API as documented in:
https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/reference/api/docker-io_api/#delete-a-user-repository

I've just tested a delete of a test image with curl:

```
curl -X DELETE -u "$user:$pass" https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/$namespace/$reponame/
```

Replace `$user` and `$pass` with your user and password on the Docker Hub, respectively; and replace `$namespace` (in my case it's the same as the `$user`) and `$reponame` with the image name (in my case was `test`).

Comment: This deletes the full image. How do I delete a particular tag?

Comment: There's no way to delete a particular tag with the API at the moment.

Comment: The linked doc is dead

Answer (score 11):

You can delete any `<TAG>` from your Docker Hub `<REPO>` by using `curl` and REST API to the Docker Hub website (at `https://hub.docker.com/v2/`) rather that to the Docker Hub registry (at `docker.io`). So if you are not afraid of using an undocumented API, this currently works:

```
curl -i -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: JWT $HUB_TOKEN" \
  https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/<HUB_USERNAME>/<REPO>/tags/<TAG>/
```

The `HUB_TOKEN` is a JSON Web Token passed using `Authorization` HTTP header, and it can be obtained by posting your credendials in JSON format to the `/v2/users/login/` Docker Hub endpoint:

```
HUB_TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\": \"$HUB_USERNAME\", \"password\": \"$HUB_PASSWORD\"}" https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ | jq -r .token)
```

*2FA => Personal Access Token*

Note than when you have 2FA enabled, you’ll need a [personal access token](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/) (the only password accepted by the API when using 2FA).

Comment: Getting `403 Forbidden` (not `401 Unauthorized`) when I do this...

Comment: @ThomasHirsch could you try to remove the single quotes in `"'${HUB_USERNAME}'"` and `"'${HUB_PASSWORD}'"`? After changing this I was able to remove a tag.

Comment: @030 Thanks, I had solved it in the meantime.

Comment: After some testing of getting the HUB_TOKEN (under 2FA), I eliminated all single quotes and switched to the more convoluted but definitely working version with double quotes throughout (escaped when nested)

Comment: This works but the API has changed to `https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/<org>/repositories/<repo>/tags/<tag>`. [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/#tag/repositories)

Answer (score 5):

Dockerhub has a REST backEnd, then you can use it... it is just skipping the FE...

For example:

```bash
export USERNAME=myuser
export PASSWORD=mypass
export ORGANIZATION=myorg # (if it's personal, then it's your username)
export REPOSITORY=myrepo
export TAG=latest

curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -X "DELETE" https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories/$ORGANIZATION/$REPOSITORY/tags/$TAG/
```

This will delete one tag...

In my case, I have microservices, then the REPOSITORY = the Microservice Name...

If I want to delete all the older images, I can iterate on this....

Comment: I only get `{"detail": "Invalid username/password"}` as a response, though I've checked the username and password carefully.

Comment: Mr @DavidParks have you check if you are at the right organization? Also, check if you have enough rights... ‍♂️ it could be that you don't have enough rights to the specific repo...

Comment: The backend API would have been nice. Looks like the API might have been changed. This solution is not working anymore. At least, I did not get it to work. the curl delete request with user and password is going through without error, but no response from the server

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the new BETA (*as of 2022-01*) Docker Hub API

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/

and the `docker-hub` [CLI tool](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/#tag/resources) among a few other options.

```sh
hub-tool login
hub-tool tag rm myrepo/myimage:mytag
```

Comment: is this tested?

Comment: @cenestpamoi How do you mean? The CLI tool is built by the folks at Docker, so although officially experimental, it does work in general. https://github.com/docker/hub-tool#readme

Comment: Works perfectly on GitHub actions with an access token: https://github.com/sudo-bot/docker-rustpython/blob/53f16c3265db556be0248b45281180e319df492c/.github/workflows/publish.yml#L106

Answer (score 1):

For any PowerShell friends.

```
$params = @{username='mickey';password='minnie'}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ -Method POST -Body $params
$token = $response.token;

$orgName = "mickey" #organization or user name
$repoName = "disney"
$Uri = $("https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$orgName/$repoName/")

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Delete -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization="JWT " + $token; Accept= 'application/json' }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. For a shortcut, Open dev tools in Chrome, go to the network tab. Delete a tag manually from Docker Hub. You will see a request on the network tab in dev tools that goes to https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories//tags/. Just right click on that request, Copy, Copy as Curl. It should look something like this...

curl "https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories//tags//" -X DELETE -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://cloud.docker.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: https://cloud.docker.com/user/repository/registry-1.docker.io/reponame/tags' -H 'Cookie: ' --compressed