# Incorrectly pushed docker image to dockerhub. How to delete?

Tags: docker, azure-aks, dockerhub

I was intending to push docker images to a private repo in azure.
However, I was logged in my to Dockerhub account when I carelessly pushed the image with tagname in azure repo format (e.g. myprivaterepo.azurecr.io/myfolder/myimage:0.0.4).

How do I delete this image?

When I login to another PC, and login to dockerhub, I can pull this exact version from the command line.

My Dockerhub web page only allows me to view repositories under my Dockerhub account.
"myimage" does not appear inside my Dockerhub Repositories list.
I also can't view other repositories inside Dockerhub. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove an image tag from Docker Hub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680703/remove-an-image-tag-from-docker-hub)

Comment: Than you for your answer. In the end, it was a newbie mistake. I followed an incorrect way of checking what credential is currently logged in. This incorrect way always shows the dockerhub credential even right after docker-login on the azure repo. I am quite confident that my image is only pushed to the azure repo.
This is the link to the incorrect way of checking the current credential:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55744359/9952864

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to repository section of your docker hub account home page
2. Check if image is available
3. If image available go inside it and select from left checkbox and delete the image
4. If image is not available , then mostly it is only in you local system , you can prune the images from your local system using: **docker image prune** command or directly remove image using: d**ocker rmi**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end, I think I did not accidentally push the image to dockerhub. Newbie mistake :-)

Comment: Okay , great to hear that your problem is solved @remondo.