# Docker private registry - How to manage images stored on the registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a local insecure Docker registry setup on a server for testing. I used the official docker tutorial for guidance. https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

I understand how to configure, push, pull, etc. from the registry server. From my understanding the registry operates as a kind of key/value storage for images. Registry architecture looks like this. [image: Docker Registry Architecture]

I haven't been able to find anything in the Docs or online that concerns removing images from the registry. Once an image is pushed, how can I remove it completely so that other docker instances can no longer pull that image from the registry? For instance, lets say I update some image. I want the servers to only pull the updated image without access to the older image.

Does anyone know how this is handled? I tried using `docker exec` to sh into the registry container and the manually deleting the image. I wasn't quite sure what to delete and this doesn't seem like the proper way. If I push an image to the registry with the same name as an existing image, will it override the existing image? Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Whenever you are pulling the image you can set that only the "latest" image should be pulled. Also for deleting the docker images you can use https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71576754/596285

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove images from your registry, you need to run the [garbage collector](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/#run-garbage-collection).

Before doing that, you should mark the images you want to be deleted. This is done via the API.

But there are plenty of CLI tools that help you to manage your container registry.

- https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/tree/main/cmd/crane
- https://github.com/genuinetools/reg
- https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli