# How to delete tags in local Docker registry?

Tags: docker-registry, podman

I'm running a [container Docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) on Podman. I'm currently learning and while doing that I'm pushing one image with the different tags on the local registry.

But I'm having trouble removing the tag from the registry.
I'm able to remove the tag(or untag) from an image(stored locally) with the command
`podman rmi [CONTAINER]`
But when I try to run the same command on a tag which is on the local registry it doesn't find it even though I can see it when I run
`podman images`

What am I missing?

Comment: Unless podman has their own CLI for this, I believe this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71576754/596285

Comment: I flagged the post myself since its duplicated to what you provided already. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your registry container with environment variable `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true`

The environment variable REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true is telling registry open to support deleting the image

Answer (score 0):

The command to remove specific tags from a local repository is

```
podman rmi CONTAINER:TAG
```

I didn't think of trying this one when asking the question.

Edit: As @BMitch mentioned this command does nothing on the registry.

Comment: That command shouldn't do anything with the docker registry. You would still be able to pull the image from the registry after deleting it from the podman image store. I suspect the question needs to be rephrased and tags adjusted to avoid confusion.