# How to set Kubernetes image pull retry limit

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-container

Kubernetes ends up with long running pods when an image specified for a container is purged from an image repository.  These deployments are created by a continuous integration system and sometimes pipelines are run or rerun when images have been purged.

The status from `kubectl get pods` shows `ImagePullBackOff`.

What should be set in the kube config yaml file to stop these pods from running for days?  Ideally we just want the Image to be pulled a couple of times and then fail if it's unsuccessful.

The pod definition is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-missing-image

spec:
  containers:

  - image: missingimage

    name: test
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "10000Mi"
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        port: 5678
        path: /somePath
      initialDelaySeconds: 360
      periodSeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 30

  restartPolicy: Never
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need it? I really cannot understand. What good is having any k8s resource such as Deployment or StatefulSet, which can't be started, but existing in the cluster?

Comment: We are creating kubernetes deployments as part of our continuous integration pipelines.  As a result sometimes dependent images are missing if they are older than a threshold age.

Answer (score 1):

AKAIK, the only way to control this as of this writing is with the [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)  in the container spec.

You may set it to `Never` but your pod will not run since the image is not present locally. Or you can set it to `IfNotPresent` but somehow you will have to have to create an image with that specific tag locally in your K8s nodes. Either option is not ideal, but I believe there might be a rationale to have it go into `ImagePullBackOff`: people would want to to know why their pod is not running.

So IMO the bigger question is why would you want to delete/invalidate images in your docker registry that are still running in your cluster? Why not update the `pods/deployments/daemonsets/replicasets/statefulsets` with the latest images prior to deleting or invalidating an image in the docker registry (also called deploy)?

The general practice could be something like this:

```
create new image => deploy it => make sure everything is ok => 
{
  ok => invalidate the old image tag.
  not ok => rollback => delete new image tag => go back to create new image => create new image tag.
}
```

Note, layers, and images are not deleted in a docker registry. You can delete or overwrite tags: [How to delete images from a private docker registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436742/how-to-delete-images-from-a-private-docker-registry?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks, we'll query whether the image exists then before creating the pod.