# How to delete all tags of a specific image from docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43786939/5372462) answer I was able to delete all tags of a specific image, but the image name still appeard in the catalog running:

```
http://YourPrivateRegistyIP:5000/v2/_catalog
```

What is the way to delete the image from the docker-registry without leaving a trace?

Answer (score 1):

I found that it's easier and faster to remove the entire image_name root directory from the filesystem like so:

```
rm -r <root>/v2/repositories/${image_name}
```

afterwards running the garbage collector:

```
bin/registry garbage-collect  /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

will clean the leftover blobs.

Deleting the image_name directory is faster then deleting every tag seperately using the API, and in addition it will also remove the image name from the catalog