# Creating tag for image pushing to repository

Tags: docker

I have created repository in docker cloud `andrejvi/andrejvi_repo` and would like to place there image I have created.

Image name is `dev_centos32`

I do push:

```
sudo docker push andrejvi/dev_centos32
```

According to my understanding I must create tag for this image. How to do that?

Trying to push:

```
sudo docker push andrejvi/andrejvi_repo:dev_centos32
```

got error:

```
An image does not exist locally with the tag: andrejvi/andrejvi_repo:
```

UPD

I changed tag, but still can't push to repository

```
docker tag dev_centos32 andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32

sudo docker push andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32

The push refers to repository [docker.io/andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32]
0afb6e2f03f2: Preparing 
d70d6ed6bc21: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

UPD

Got error while login

```
$ sudo docker login andrejvi
Username: andrejvi
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://andrejvi/v2/: dial tcp: lookup andrejvi on 127.0.1.1:53: server misbehaving
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create named and latest tag in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080706/how-to-create-named-and-latest-tag-in-docker)

Comment: `git tag dev_centos32 andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32` and `git push andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32`

Comment: I have changed tag, but still can't push. More details in UPD in question body

Comment: are you trying to push to docker.io? Not sure about this repo but It could be the matter of you credentials and account

Comment: Are you using [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/) as your registry?

Comment: Got error while login. More details in UPD

Answer (score 1):

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

You need to login into Docker Hub/Docker Cloud repository using the command:

```
docker login
```

Take a look at [Push images to Docker Cloud](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/).

Comment: Apart from this, there might also be a problem with `andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32` used as a name. It doen't seem to follow the `username/image_name:tag_name` format.

Comment: You don't have to write the :tag_name, if you don't write the default is latest.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
docker login
docker tag dev_centos32 {docker-hub-username}/andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32
docker image push {docker-hub-username}/andrejvi/andrejvi_repo/dev_centos32
```