# Correct way of managing docker hub image versions

Tags: docker

Ideal scenario:

I create a new tag for an existing docker hub repo:

`docker build . -t org/repo:v1`

I have a docker-compose that reads that tag:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    image: org/repo
    ...
```

However, this does not work because there's no tag of latest.

Is there a way to get this behavior?  Otherwise, every deploy has to modify the `docker-compose.yml` which seems stupid.

I have a solution that is ugly but it works:
I simply have to retag and push a latest tag.

```
docker tag org/repo:v1 org/repo:latest
docker push org/repo:latest
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[**The misunderstood Docker tag: `latest`**](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375)" from [**Marc Campbell**](https://twitter.com/mccode): `latest` is a tag referencing a tag pushed:

> ### Latest is just a tag with a special name.
>
> It doesn’t mean anything special unless you use a pretty specific build/tag/push/pull/run pattern.
>
> **“Latest” simply means “the last build/tag that ran without a specific tag/version specified”**.
>
> In other words, you could build new versions like this:
>
> ```
> sudo docker build -t marc/test .
> sudo docker tag marc/test marc/test:2 
> ...
> sudo docker build -t marc/test .
> sudo docker tag marc/test:3
> ...
> ```
>
> But this is a little odd. Why would I have to tag everything twice?
>
> If you are shipping Docker images to a production environment, you should just ignore the `latest` tag.
>   Don’t use it. Don’t be tempted by it.
>   It’s easy to look at it and think that your deployment script should just pull “latest” and your build process will ensure that’s valid. It takes a lot of discipline to make that work. Just version your tags. Every time.

See more with "[Docker: The latest Confusion](http://container-solutions.com/docker-latest-confusion/)" from **[Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat)**:

> If the repository is to be uploaded to the Docker Hub, the repository name must be prefixed with a slash and the Docker Hub user name e.g. `amouat/myrepo:mytag`.
>
> **The trick is of course, if you leave the tag part out (e.g. `docker tag myrepo:1.0 myrepo`), Docker will automatically give it the tag `latest`**.

See "[How to create named and `latest` tag in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36398336/6309)".

> Just because an image is tagged latest, does not mean that it is the most up-to-date image within its repository.
>
> So what happens if you do the pull on a repository with no latest tag?
>   This:
>
> ```
> $ docker pull amouat/myrepo
> Pulling repository amouat/myrepo
> 2015/01/21 12:04:06 Tag latest not found in repository amouat/myrepo
> ```

---

The OP adds:

> The issue I had is trying to keep the dev environment synced with latest changes without having to manually edit the docker-compose.yml with the new tag every change.

For that, I always maintain a "deployed" tag which is shifting (applied only when I upgrade an image tag) and used in scripts/docker-compose.yml.

I prefer building my own image in order to [add `LABEL`s](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) which are used to memorize what that "deployed" tag actually refers to (I setup a LABEL named "tag" with  the actual tag name in it).

Comment: Thank you!  I think the approach then is to avoid using the repo in development in the `docker-compose.yml` and instead reference the remote repository in production deploys.  The issue I had is trying to keep the dev environment synced with latest changes without having to manually edit the `docker-compose.yml` with the new tag every change.

Comment: @user3162553 I have edited my answer to address your comment.