# Tagging docker image with multiple tags

Tags: docker, artifactory

Is it possible to ensuring that only a single docker image is created with multiple tags and how do I get these tags to appear in the Docker repository(JFrog) after a docker push command?

A Related question I used to add multiple tags at once on build: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35565384/3762850

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

target_image="<my-remote-site>:8081/<docker-artifactory>/<repository-key>"

tag_a="First-Tag"
tag_b="Second-Tag"

sudo docker login -u <user-name>-p <user-password> <my-remote-site>:8081
sudo docker build -t "${target_image}:${tag_a}" -t "${target_image}:${tag_b}" .
sudo docker push "${target_image}:${tag_a}" "${target_image}:${tag_b}"
```

Comment: tag once in the build and using that tag assign other tags

Comment: Tagging an image does not create a new one. It just attaches another name to an existing image.

Comment: @t-prisar, I run it automatically using bash script. Could you please fix my script?

Comment: @Henry, Unfortunately after the push I get two different images within my repository or only the one I use in the push command.

Comment: For sure it won't be "different images". Are you worrying if the same image is stored twice?

Comment: @Henry, Within AWS ECR for instance I only have single docker image with multiple tags, on the other Docker Registry(JFrog) I see two different images

Comment: It may depend on the repo implementation. Usually, the layers are shared (even between different images when they share a common base layer). Are you sure there is not a gap between what you get shown on the UI and what is really stored?

Comment: Check out this blog - https://dille.name/blog/2018/09/20/how-to-tag-docker-images-without-pulling-them/ which would help you to understand more about how the tagging works.

Comment: It may show up as two different images in the artifact browser, but those images contain the same set of files with the same checksums. In Artifactory, each of those files are only stored once. And it doesn't look any different to the Docker client. So you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create multiple tag docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928780/create-multiple-tag-docker-image)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35565384

Answer (score 3):

docker tag helps to put tags to an image. It can be used to create a new tag with a previous tag.

```
#!/bin/bash

target_image="<my-remote-site>:8081/<docker-artifactory>/<repository-key>"

tag_a="First-Tag"
tag_b="Second-Tag"

sudo docker login -u <user-name>-p <user-password> <my-remote-site>:8081
sudo docker build -t "${target_image}:${tag_a}" .
sudo docker tag "${target_image}:${tag_a}" "${target_image}:${tag_b}"
sudo docker push "${target_image}:${tag_a}" "${target_image}:${tag_b}"
```