# What is the docker image name and is the name unique?

Tags: docker, docker-image

When I run `docker images` I can see the repository, tag, imageid, size. But there is no image name column.

Can we say that image name is a combination of repository and tag -  `repository:tag`? And that at any point of time there can be only 1 image with the same repository name and tag value combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to both of your questions is **YES**

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/):

> An image name is made up of slash-separated name components, optionally prefixed by a registry hostname.

Basically, this is how your docker image name looks like:

`<hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>`

Now we can have multiple repositories in our docker hub account but, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/), `The repository name needs to be unique in that namespace`

Also, within a docker repository, [a docker image can have multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928780/create-multiple-tag-docker-image), but multiple docker images **cannot** have the same tag.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with the take of this answer (there is no ground truth however), but the last statement is kind of wrong: if we define a docker image by its digest, then yes multiple images can have the same tag. Think about Python with tag 3.6 for Intel and ARM architectures: two images, same tag. And yes, the entire topic is a huge mess. No one's fault.

Comment: I'm having problems with terminology here. `<hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>` is not an "image name" per the linked docs; it is a combination of image name `<hub-user>/<repo-name>` and tag name `<tag>`. For one, the allowed characters for the image name are different from the allowed characters for the tag name. I have yet to find the proper term for an image name together with a tag name `<image-name>:<tag-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we say that image name is a combination of repository and tag - repository:tag?

I think not.

The [documentation for the `docker tag` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) has two examples:

> To tag a local image with **name** “httpd” ...
>
> ```
> $ docker tag httpd fedora/httpd:version1.0
> ```

and

> To tag a local image with **name** “httpd” and **tag** “test” ...
>
> ```
> $ docker tag httpd:test fedora/httpd:version1.0.test
> ```

So at least in this doc `httpd:test` is treated as name:tag combination.